# How do Media Player Android apps like MXPlayer and MoboPlayer play unsupported file formats like MKV?

Tags: android, video, codec, mkv

Android doesn't support many media file formats (files like .mkv), by default. But players like MXPlayer and MoboPlayer enables you to play such files. How do these applications work?
Is there any programming tutorials or articles explaining how it is done?

Comment: mkv is just a container. you can use many different video/audio codecs inside...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Android does not support all the media formats by default. Hence to support an unsupported format, applications like MoboPlayer perform standard media player tasks themselves using a combination of Java and native code via JNI.

To understand more, let us see what a media player does to play a media file and how these are performed by MoboPlayer like apps in Android.

`Typical tasks of a Media Player`

A player needs to perform following tasks (a) Demux the file format and extract the video/audio (b) Decode the video and the audio (c) Display the video and Play the audio.  Let us consider how these three areas can be handled in case of MoboPlayer like player.

`File format Demux`

Android does not support all the file format containers, by default. For example, ASF (file format of WMV files) is not supported. Hence a player needs to have it's own demuxer to do the job. libavformat (used by FFMPEG) is a leading open source demux library.

`Video/Audio decode`

libavcodec (used by FFMPEG) is a leading open source decoder library that decodes demuxed stream and produces uncompressed raw output frames. Hence it is often used by players like MoboPlayer.

`Video display`

There are two options to display a video. Players use either  `SurfaceView` buffers or OpenGL accelerated buffers. Android provides a cast of java Surface object (abstraction of underlying surface flinger object) to an internal native object called `NativeWindow`, which can then be accessed by the native code.

ICS (Android 4.0) onwards, Android provides access to the OpenGL accelerated buffers (`SurfaceTexure` and `TextureView`) too. These can be used to display the video as well.

`Audio playout`

Players can directly interact with the `AudioTrack` object provided at the Java level to play the decoded audio samples.

Comment: OakBytes is right. These players use a 3rd party parsers/software-decoders either proprietary or FFMPEG.

Some players also use opengl for display. Majority of them use the SuraceView and it's native counterpart NativeWindow to display decoded video.

This works without the native framework and sits parallel to it. Hence moboplayer also provides for an option to use software or hardware decoders.